# view created table in microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am running part of a query in Microsoft SQL server management studio

```
Select  Table1.Column1

into #Table2 

from Table1
```

now it has created the table but I actually want to view this table with my eyes but I cannot seem to find where the table is stored. Please could someone help me find it?

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see any command to create a table. Do those lines create a table?

Comment: yes. it create a temp table

Answer (score 2):

That is a [temporary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#temporary-tables). It will be created in the tempdb system database and you can see it by going to `tempdb -> Temporary Tables`.

[image]

Comment: This is what I am looking for but for some reason the table is not there. Even though I can see the result when I use select * from #Table2

Comment: It will be there until you close the session. When the session is closed, the table will not exist anymore.

Comment: what do you mean by closed the session?

Comment: When you run the query on SSMS and then close that window where the query was running, the session is closed and all temporary objects do not exist anymore. If you keep your window where you run your query open after creating the temporary table, you should still be able to see it.

Comment: Yes I have tried but it is still not there it is very strange, it should be there.

Answer (score 2):

Any tables where its name start with `#` is a Temporary Table. Exactly as the name suggests, it's temporary, and only exists for the same time the connection that created it does (or it is dropped).

If you want to view the data from a temporary table, you would do so like any other table `SELECT * FROM #Table2;`. .

I imagine what your really after is to not use a temporary table, so drop the `#` from the name, and the new table will be created in the database you are connected to.